Unable to use Win32gui and Windows_Cursers
I am trying to make a reading app of the Authorized King James Bible with Python!
I created the script with the help of A.I with some fonts and stuff. Though when I try to run it, it says win32gui, win32gui is not installed.
I went to downgrade Python to 3.6.2 and was able to install it. Though it still says it can't be found.
I am using Pyinstaller and Auto-Py-To-Exe to convert.
I tried using a virtual machine and downgrading Python.
import os
import ctypes
import colorama
from colorama import Style, Fore, Back, init
from rich.console import Console
import shutil
import windows_curses
import sys
import win32gui
import pyautogui
import argparse
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Key
import textwrap
import keyboard
import time
import subprocess


# Detect the environment (terminal or cmd)
if sys.stdout.isatty():
    # Use the hotkey for **Windows Terminal**
    pyautogui.hotkey('win', 'up')

#Get the console window
hWnd = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow()
size = os.get_terminal_size()

def get_window_position(hwnd):
    rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    x, y, width, height = rect
    return x, y

# Get the handle of the active window
active_window = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()

# Get the position of the active window
x_pos, y_pos = get_window_position(active_window)

# Title page
columns = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns

print("Authorized King James Bible".center(columns))
print("Thy word is a lamp unto my feet, and a light unto my path.".center(columns))
print("- Psalms 119:105".center(columns))

# Genesis title and chapter 1
print("\n" + Fore.CYAN + "THE FIRST BOOK OF MOSES CALLED GENESIS" + Fore.RESET + "\n")
print(Fore.GREEN + "Chapter 1" + Fore.RESET + "\n")

    # Genesis chapter 1 verses
    
    #Day 1
    # Get the terminal size
    size = os.get_terminal_size()
    # Use the columns attribute as the width
    print(textwrap.fill("1:1 ¶ IN the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.", width=size.columns)) 
    print(textwrap.fill("1:2 And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the waters.", width=size.columns))
    print(textwrap.fill("1:3 And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.", width=size.columns))
    print(textwrap.fill("1:4 And God saw the light, that \x1B[3mit was\x1B[0m good: and God divided the light from the darkness.", width=size.columns))
    print(textwrap.fill("1:5 And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And the evening and morning were the first day.", width=size.columns))
    print("\n")
    
    # Pause the script
    time.sleep(0.2)
    
    # Create an argument parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--env", help="Specify the environment (terminal or cmd)", choices=['terminal', 'cmd'])
    
    # Parse the arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    # Create a keyboard controller
    keyboard = Controller()
    
    # Use the hotkey for Windows Terminal
    if args.env == 'terminal' or sys.stdout.isatty():
        with keyboard.pressed(Key.ctrl, Key.shift): 
            keyboard.press(Key.home)
            keyboard.release(Key.home)
    else:
        # Use the hotkey for CMD
        with keyboard.pressed(Key.ctrl):
            keyboard.press(Key.home)
            keyboard.release(Key.home)
            
    # Pause the script
    input("\n" + "Press Alt-Enter to Exit out of Full Screen Mode or Press Enter to exit..." + "\n")


Are you using Windows? Did you install win32gui?

Please include relevant code as text directly in the question, instead of linking to OneDrive.

I am unsure how to add the code into the question, I did install win32gui. Yes, Windows 11.

Highlight it, press Ctrl-C. Edit the question and in the question editor, press Ctrl-V. Then add triple backticks above and below.

How did you install win32gui? You likely want pywin32 (and maybe also pywin32-ctypes) instead.

I used pip install win32gui.

Also, it says no windows_curses found.

Your best bet is going with an entirely different approach - win32gui is an extremely low level manager to interface with your system. I know you used AI to generate this so you are likely less experienced with python. The program you have provided just prints the first few verses into the terminal whilst giving the user a bit of control over closing the application.
First thing: You will need a .txt copy of the bible you are trying to use.
I have located one at this link: https://openbible.com/textfiles/kjv.txt
[Verify it is the correct one].
Given that your bible text file is in the format:
BOOK CHAPTER:VERSE LOREM IPSUM ECT ECT
Then you can easily parse over the text file, index it, and split the books into separate objects. You can then have each book remember the location of each chapter [the line num].
Here is a simple parser I wrote that will give you an idea of where to go. If you are fine with it just being a terminal parser than you can just modify my code to your needs - if you are looking at making it a GUI then it is beyond the scope of my answer but look into libraries such as tkinter or pygame depending on how much you want to write. (Still use this code as the backend to actually get the data).
Ensure the bible file KJV.txt is in the same folder as your script.
class Book:
    def __init__(self, name, start_index, end_index, lines):
        self.name = name
        self.lines = lines[start_index:end_index+1]
        self.chapters = {}
        for index, line in enumerate(self.lines):
            numeric = line.split(" ")[1].split(":")[0]
            if self.chapters.get(numeric) == None:
                self.chapters[numeric] = index
                
    def get_passage(self, chapter, verse):
        index = self.chapters[str(chapter)] + int(verse) - 1
        return self.lines[index]
    
with open("KJV.txt", "r") as bible_file:
    lines = [line.strip("\n") for line in bible_file.readlines()][2:]

books = []
indices = []

book_objects = {}

for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    book = line.split(" ")[0]
    if book not in books:
        books.append(book)
        indices.append(index)

for index, book in enumerate(books):
    try: end = indices[index+1]-1
    except: end = len(lines)-1
    print("BOOK: %s AT %s" % (book, index))
    book_objects[book.lower()] = Book(book, indices[index], end, lines)

verse = book_objects["exodus"].get_passage(7, 11)
print(verse)

